# Stripe: attribute charge with single use token to customer

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm pretty sure this is a basic question, but I couldn't find the answer in the docs or on google.

I am trying to attribute a charge to a customer. 
So, I am creating a single-use token to charge a card, but I am trying to figure out how to connect that charge to a customer that I've already created. Let's say the customer doesn't want to use their previously stored credit card. Here's what I tried to do, but it is returning an error because Stripe thinks I am trying to charge the customer and the card (which is probably what I'm telling it to do, here).

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => $product_price, // amount in cents, again
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer_id,
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "Example charge"
));
```

How would someone attach a single-use token charge to a customer?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to attribute an already created charge to a customer after the charge has been created. Likewise, once a token's been used for a charge you won't be able to use it again. Instead, you'd need to create a customer object, attach that unused token as the `source`, then create the charge by passing the `customer` parameter. There's an example of all of this here:
https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later

Answer (score 0):

> For anyone finding this many years later via search

A single-use charge can be made via Stripe and attributed to a Customer *without* saving that card as a reusable source on the Customer - https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-source.

It is achieved by using the Source API in Stripe.js or Elements, that is, by creating a "standalone" `source`, not a card `token` - https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-source

When tokenizing a card, that is a reusable source that *must* be attached to a customer, when creating a source, that can be used for a single-use charge, you can *optionally* attach it to a customer for internal tracking. This source can not be used again for any future transactions.

Use the `stripe.createSource` from the Stripe.js or Elements and then pass the id of the returned object (`source.id`) to your backend, you can then use this to create a charge associated with a Customer.

PHP:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  'amount' => 1099,
  'currency' => 'eur',
  'customer' => 'cus_AFGbOSiITuJVDs',
  'source' => 'src_18eYalAHEMiOZZp1l9ZTjSU0',
]);
```

Ruby:

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
  amount: 1099,
  currency: 'eur',
  customer: 'cus_AFGbOSiITuJVDs',
  source: 'src_18eYalAHEMiOZZp1l9ZTjSU0',
})
```